# importing std::vector into python using pybind11 gives python error

Tags: pybind11

I'm trying to use pybind11's stl_bind header to no avail.  I tried this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_PLUGIN(test)
{
    py::module m("test", "pybind11 example plugin");
    py::bind_vector<std::vector<double>>(m, "std_vector");
}
```

But when I try to use "std_vector" in python I get this:

```
In [1]: import test as b

In [2]: vec = b.std_vector()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f81a62984a4e> in <module>()
----> 1 vec = b.std_vector()

ValueError: vector::reserve
```

Is this a bug, or am I using pybind11 wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing a call to the PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE macro before PYBIND11_PLUGIN(test)?

```
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<double>);
```

According to the [PyBind11 doc](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#making-opaque-types) you shoud first disable the defalut type conversion from *vector* to *list*.